# CGAL: Simplify convex polyhedra in 3D

Tags: cgal, convex, polyhedra

I have been using the [cgal](/questions/tagged/cgal) library to generate convex hulls which are further used for discrete element simulations. Currently, I am trying to make the polyhedral particles break, which is right now implemented as plane clipping of the polyhedron. The problem is that after several (sometimes even one) clipping, the polyhedrons start having "bad" attributes, such as nearly degenerate faces, nearly coplanar edges or nearly degenerate edges, which cause problems in the contact calculation. I have been looking at `CGAL/Surface_mesh_simplification` routines and used the `edge_collapse` function, but it does not preserve convexity of the particles. Is there any way to use routines from [cgal](/questions/tagged/cgal) for convex polyhedra simplifications while preserving convexity?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the function [`isotropic_remeshing()`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Polygon_mesh_processing/group__PMP__meshing__grp.html#gad3d03890515ae8103bd32a30a3486412). While there is no guarantee that the output will stay convex, the points are guaranteed to be on the input mesh. If you have some sharp edges you want to preserve, you can specify it to the function and it will take them into account.